# react native change color view in list views

Tags: reactjs, list, state, touch, native

i have an array of elements and create a list. They are all the same and I would like to change the color of the item that is touched. When creating them inside the map, I get the same state and they all change color.

I want only the touched item to change color

state of color:

const [myColorItem, setMyColorItem] = useState('#fff');

create a list items:

```
let Arr = data.hours.map((item, i) => {
return <Item key={i} myId={i} hour={item.hour} isBusy={item.isBusy}/>
```

})

the Item is:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={{ backgroundColor: myColorItem }} 
  onPress={() =>hourSelected(hour)}>
  <Text style={styles.textStyle_hour} >{hour}</Text>
  <Text style={{color: '#cacaca'}}>Disponible</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and method is:

```
const hourSelected = (hour) => {
console.log('hora selec '+hour);
setMyColorItem('#00acba');
```

};

*********UPDATE*********
Thanks for the feedback. They have helped me to form the code.

new variable:

const [itemSelectedList, setItemSelectedList] = useState([false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false])

```
const hourSelected = (myId, hour) => {
console.log('hora selec '+hour);
let selectedList = [...itemSelectedList];
selectedList[myId] = !selectedList[myId];
setItemSelectedList(selectedList);
```

};

and touch button

```
    <TouchableOpacity 
  style={{ backgroundColor: itemSelectedList[myId] ? '#00acba' : '#ffffff'  }} 
  onPress={() =>hourSelected(hour)}>
  <Text style={styles.textStyle_hour} >{hour}</Text>
  <Text style={{color: '#cacaca'}}>Disponible</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider reorganising your state like this:

```
const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = useState(null);

let Arr = data.hours.map((item, i) => {
   return <Item key={i} myId={i} hour={item.hour} isBusy={item.isBusy} />
})

<TouchableOpacity 
  style={{ backgroundColor: myId === itemSelected ? '#cacaca' : '#ffffff' }} 
  onPress={() =>hourSelected(hour,myId)}>
  <Text style={styles.textStyle_hour} >{hour}</Text>
  <Text style={{color: '#cacaca'}}>Disponible</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

const hourSelected = (hour,myId) => {
    console.log('hora selec '+hour);
    setItemSelected(myId);
};
```

Keep in mind using index as id and key is a bad practice. https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Thank you! If I select one, it changes color to "cacaca" well, if I select another, it changes color well to "cacaca" but the previous one changes color to "ffffff". I would like to keep the colors changed in the ones already pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This helps changing color for single/multiple selection items

While preparing your list you can have a flag maintained for items

```
const [responseList, setResponseList] = useState([])

 data.hours= data.hours.map(item => {
        item.isSelect = false;
        return item;
      });
      setResponseList(data.hours)
```

Next you can pass index and get single or multiple items selected

```
function setData(index) {
 let doc = []
 responseList.map(item => {
 item.select = false     
 doc.push(item)
 })
 doc[index].isSelect = true
 setResponseList(doc)
 }


var selectedColor = '#337AB7'
var defaultColor = '#A9A9A9'
```

And in list the color can be set for single/multiple selected items accordingly

```
<TouchableOpacity 
style={{ backgroundColor: item.isSelect? selectedColor : defaultColor}} 
onPress={() =>hourSelected(hour,myId)}>
<Text style={styles.textStyle_hour} >{hour}</Text>
<Text style={{color: '#cacaca'}}>Disponible</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Inorder to maintain the selection and unselected state for multiple items

```
function setData(index) {
var isSelected = responseList[index].isSelect
responseList[index].isSelect = !isSelected
let doc = []
responseList.map(item => {
  doc.push(item)
})
setResponseList(doc)
}
```

Also instead of flag you can maintain a colorTheme for each of the items while preparing list and through index the item colorTheme can be changed and would work for single as well as multiple selected items